# Connected with ftp server but files are not downloading in Spring integration could anyone fix this?

Tags: java, ftp, spring-integration

*This is my main class*

```
public class FtpInboundChannelAdapterSample {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FtpInboundChannelAdapterSample.class);
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    FtpInboundChannelAdapterSample ftp=new FtpInboundChannelAdapterSample();
    ftp.ftpDownload();



}

public void ftpDownload() throws Exception {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "META-INF/spring/integration/FtpInboundChannelAdapterSample-context.xml");

    PollableChannel ftpChannel = ctx.getBean("ftpChannel", PollableChannel.class);


    System.out.println("Files are transferred ");
    ctx.close();
}
```

}

*And my .xml is as follow*

```
<bean id="ftpClientFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="${host}"/>
    <property name="port" value="${availableServerPort}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${userid}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
</bean>

<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound"
            channel="ftpChannel"
            session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
            filename-pattern="*.*"
            auto-create-local-directory="true"
            delete-remote-files="false"
            remote-directory="ftp://portal.********.com/foldername/"
            local-directory="${localDir}">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>



<int:channel id="ftpChannel">
    <int:queue/>
</int:channel>
```

Is this a way to give the remote directory path?

remote-directory="ftp://portal.********.com/foldername/"

or

remote-directory="/ftpSample/"

I tried both but not downloading from server

If I'm using localhost with FileZilla server it was downloading..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is `remote-directory="/ftpSample/"` - you don't need a URL because the connection is specified by the session factory.

Are you sure you need the leading `/`, should it be `remote-directory="ftpSample/"` ?

Turn on DEBUG logging and check the server logs as well.

Comment: Actually i tried to connect with my colleague system as consider as a server, ftp connection has been established and the log printed in that system was give below

Comment: Don't put stuff like that in another answer; delete it and edit your question instead. Also, you need to format it better. Certainly looks like a permissions problem `Can't open data connection for transfer of "/"` - try removing the leading slash.

Comment: It will help others if you "accept" the answer (click the tick/check mark on the left below the vote buttons).

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:
`remote-directory="ftps://portal.********.com/foldername/"` or
`remote-directory="sftp://portal.********.com/foldername/"`